# Doctrine 2 / Symfony Many To One getting objects

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have three tables/entities:

- Games
- SiteGames
- Sites

I must write query in Doctrine 2 which would get all games (as objects) available for specific site (got this specific site as object).
The only relations (Many to One) are in table/entity SiteGame and it contains columns/objects:

- game/game_id
- site/site_id

Normally the raw SQL would look like (and would work):

```
SELECT g FROM site_games s INNER JOIN games g ON g.id=s.game_id WHERE site_id='4';
```

This what i tried in Doctrine but failed:

```
$qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select("s.game")
            ->from("MyBundle:SiteGame","s")
            ->where("s.site = :site")
            ->setParameter("site",$site);
```

Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression.

```
$qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select("g")
            ->from("MyBundle:SiteGame","s")
            ->join("s.game","g")
            ->where("s.site = :site")
            ->setParameter("site",$site);
```

Error: Cannot select entity through identification variables without choosing at least one root entity alias.

And many many more various combinations with similar errors.

I could not find anything helpful on entire internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume the `Games` entity does not have a `OneToMany` relation back to `SiteGames`. You have several options here:

- if `SiteGames` does not have any other attributes just `game` and `site` you can remove that entity entirely and use a proper [`ManyToMany`](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-bidirectional)  mapping
- add a [`OneToMany`](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional) mapping to `Games`
- as of doctrine 2.4 you can use the arbitrary join syntax, and write something like this:

  ```
  $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
      ->select('Game')
      ->from('MyBundle:Game', 'Game')
      ->join('MyBundle:SiteGame', 'SiteGame', 'WITH', 'SiteGame.game = Game AND SiteGame.site = :site')
      ->setParameter('site', $site)
      ->getQuery()
      ->getResult();
  ```

I would go with the first option.